# Como restringir os valores de uma data em um campo de um formulário em java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Tenho um formulário construído com `Swing` (Java) que possui alguns campos, dentre eles existe um que é  a Data de Nascimento (uma String que recebe o valor de uma data e possui um campo formatado `##/##/####`.) que é representado pela variável `jTFDataNascimento` que é um `JFormattedTextField`.

Como poderia fazer para que o usuario não colocasse datas absurdas como:
  **11/20/2090**   ou **11/10/1890**?

A unica validação que faço é checar se os campos estão vazios:

```
if(jTFDataNascimento.getText().equals("  /  /    "))...
```

Queria validar também as datas, quanto ao seus valores e não validar somente quanto ao conteudo estar vazio ou não, é possível?

Não há restrições quanto ao campo ser uma String ou data, eu coloquei String por praticidade!

Já trabalhei em alguns projetos java Web e fazer essa validação é algo trivial em uma pagina html5, tudo que aprendi sobre datas no java é sobre a versão java7, penso que no java8 isso seja mais simples de se fazer.

Acho que deve existir um código que recebe uma data e verifique se ele é menor que de uma data previamente cadastrada no sistema  e também veja se essa mesma data é maior que a maior data previamente cadastras.
ou  melhor ainda
o método recebe três datas (dataAtual, dataRemota, dataNascimento) e verifique se a dataNascimento é menor que a data dataAtual  ou se essa mesma data é maior  que a data dataRemota.

```
public boolean validarData(LocalDate dataAtual, LocalDate dataRemota, LocalDate dataNascimento){
    //codigo que não sei ainda...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Veja esse exemplo no SOen: [JFormattedTextField : input time duration value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234726/jformattedtextfield-input-time-duration-value/2241997#2241997)

Comment: São duas dúvidas diferentes na mesma pergunta, segue outro link pra segunda duvida, mas aconselho separar a segunda duvida em outra pergunta; http://www.botecodigital.info/java/a-api-de-data-do-java-8/

Comment: @DiegoF Sem palavras véio!! Você me deu dicas construtivas!! Isso levanta a moral do stackoverflow!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar duas formas para fazer essa comparação, com a nova classe do java8, a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), ou a tradicional [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

Usando `LocalDate`:

```
public class CompararDataTeste {

    public static boolean validarDataLocalDate(LocalDate dataAtual, LocalDate dataRemota, LocalDate dataNascimento) {

        return dataNascimento.isAfter(dataRemota) || dataNascimento.isBefore(dataAtual);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    LocalDate localDataAtual = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate localDataNascimento = LocalDate.of(1998, 3, 27);
    LocalDate localDataRemota = LocalDate.of(1990, 1, 1);
    
    System.out.println(validarDataLocalDate(localDataAtual, localDataRemota, localDataNascimento));
    
        }
    }
```

Já com `Date`, ficaria assim:

```
public class CompararDataTeste {

    public static boolean validarDataDate(Date dataAtual, Date dataRemota, Date dataNascimento) {

        return dataNascimento.after(dataRemota) || dataNascimento.before(dataAtual);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Date dataRemota = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("01/01/1990");
    Date dataNascimento = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse("27/03/1998");
    Date dataAtual = new Date();
    System.out.println(validarDataDate(dataAtual, dataRemota, dataNascimento));
    
        }
    }
```

Ambos os exemplos vão retornar `true`, pois `dataNascimento` é posterior a `dataRemota`, e anterior a `dataAtual`. Você pode ver ambos os exemplos funcionando aqui no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/RvwrbP).

Não ficou muito claro na pergunta se ambas as condições precisam ser verdadeiras para ser uma data válida, caso seja este caso, basta substituir o operador `||` por `&&`.

---

## Adendo

Caso você receba uma `String` e queira fazer a conversão para `LocalDate`, além da propria data, você precisa fazer algo parecido como é feito para a classe `Date`, criar um `DateTimeFormatter` e fazer um parse passando as duas informações como argumentos:

```
String stringData = "27/03/2016";
DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate sData = LocalDate.parse( stringData , fmt2 );
```

Como você está fazendo uso de `textFields`, vai precisar fazer uma mescla do exemplo acima antes de passar sua data para o método já exemplificado.

**Referências:**

[How to compare LocalDate instances Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201103/how-to-compare-localdate-instances-java-8)

[A API de data do JAVA 8](http://www.botecodigital.info/java/a-api-de-data-do-java-8/)

[LocalDate - Documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado Doutor Diego, formidável!! Tiro e queda!

Comment: @PenaPintada Disponha! Fiz um adendo na resposta, para mostrar como passar um `String` para `LocalDate`, já que está usando campo de textos, seria interessante  saber como se faz.

Comment: Muito obrigado, o adendo foi esclarecedor, ajudou muito!